# How to turn off autoindent

Tags: vi

I cannot seem to turn off autoindent in vi. It seems to be limited only to the comment character **#**
If I begin a new line with spaces and a **#** then the following lines begin with the same, even though I dont really want that.
This behavior is not reproduced if I begin a new line with only spaces or tabs.
I have the following set

```
noautoindent
nocindent
nosmartindent
nocopyindent
```

Not sure whether it matters but for nocindent the following is set too

```
nocindent
  comments=:#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending some time on this, I was able to come up with a solution (actually, two).
It turns out that formatoptions was getting set to "croql" for some reason, only when I opened a certain file. The solution is to disable the "r" option. You can find more details on the "r" option here http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#fo-table

Solution 1

```
:set formatoptions-=r
```

The short form will work too

```
 :set fo-=r
```

Solution 2

```
:set fo=tcql
```

To confirm that the changes are in place, use the following command

```
:set fo
```

Option "r" should not be present.